# Windows Credentials dialog won't show when navigating using axWebBrowser

Tags: c#, active-directory, axwebbrowser

I'm doing some maintenance work on a legacy app that is using `AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser` to access in an intranet website.  The web site required Windows Authentication.  When I navigate to the page directly using IE I get a pop-up asking for Active Directory credentials, but when I try to `WebBrowser.navigate()` to it I immediately get:
[image: WebBrowser response]

Refreshing the page using the provided link gives me an UNAUTHORIZED response.

Is there something I need to do when setting up the `AxWebBrowser` control so that it properly displays the credential popup?

Comment: Surely thats more an IE setting than a coding thing surely?

Comment: I would think maybe, but it the credential dialog pops up nicely when in IE.  Since the AxWebBrowser is essentially IE, I would expect it to do the same when I navigate to the same page, no?

Comment: depends, it maybe the axwebbrowser doesnt do those kinds of things as it expects you to control them, does it not have any form of on auth request options? (I dont have axwebbrowser to hand)

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me for this.  It appears that the credentials are just expected to pop up.  Perhaps they don't pop up because it is within another program, and not just IE?

Comment: Do you have anything along the line of respond to response codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the answer, and as usual it's a coding issue.  The original author of this code set it so that no pop-ups could happen (`axwebbrowser.silent = true`).  He did it to prevent Javascript errors popping up (as opposed to, you know, FIXING the javascript errors), but a side effect was that the dialog box for credential entry wouldn't show up.  Removal of that line fixed the issue.